# How to configure OpenSCEP in linux

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, openscep

I am trying to setup OpenSCEP in linux. I downloaded the openscep package from http://openscep.othello.ch/. I went though SETUP file which was in the package. The steps mentioned in that file is not working. Can anyone help me on this..?

Thanks in advance..